# Unix command substitution when using sqlplud

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

Trying to invoke a sql file from unix shells script.

ExecuteSql1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
## steps to get the connection and form it.
result=`sqlplus -S ${connectURL} << EOF
SET PAGES 0 lines 800
@ /sql/testQuery.sql ${LOGFILE} 
EOF`

echo $result
```

output of the above script (works as expected without exception)

MODULUS BEFORE: 0 MODULUS AFTER: 16 No errors.

ExecuteSql2.sh {**NOTE the starting space is PRESERVED below result variable**}

```
#!/bin/sh
result=`sqlplus -S ${dbConnect} << EOF
      SET PAGES 0 lines 800
      @ /sql/testQuery.sql ${LOGFILE};
      EOF`

echo $result
```

When executing `ExecuteSql2.sh`, the output looks like below:

ExecuteSql2.sh: line 147: warning: here-document at line 144 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
MODULUS BEFORE: 0 MODULUS AFTER: 16 No errors. SP2-0042: unknown command "EOF" - rest of line ignored.

---

using, didn't know when using the  `` built in command substitution with space causes this issue.

### Any specific reason for this?

testQuery.sql:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
set heading off verify off feedback off echo off

SPOOL &1

declare
 modulus NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MODULUS BEFORE: '||modulus);

select mod(100,21) into modulus from dual;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MODULUS AFTER: '||modulus);

end;
/

SET ECHO ON FEEDBACK ON
SHOW ERRORS
SPOOL OFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation [3.6 Redirections - 3.6.6 Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
>   current source until a line containing only word (**with no trailing
>   blanks**) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used
>   as the standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified) for a
>   command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>         here-document delimiter
> delimiter
> ```

So your code should be

```
result=`sqlplus -S ${dbConnect} << EOF
      SET PAGES 0 lines 800
      @ /sql/testQuery.sql ${LOGFILE};
EOF
`
```

And note that the final "`" should be below the EOF, althoug I think is better to use the notation `$()` as in

```
result=$(sqlplus -S ${dbConnect} << EOF
      SET PAGES 0 lines 800
      @ /sql/testQuery.sql ${LOGFILE};
EOF
)
```